# обязательное поле при его отображении

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

есть поля выбора select из дувх значений.
при выборе одного из значения появляется доп поле.
как сделать чтобы оно было обязательное если он есть 
и не обязательно если его нет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример (Если выбрано поле 1 - то показывается доп. поле и оно обязательное, если выбрано 2, то поле не обязательное и скрыть.

```js
    function change1() {
        let val = $('#sel1').val(); //Получаем значение поля селект.
        if (val === "1"){ //Если значение 1 то добавляем "required" и удаляем класс "hidden" , который скрывает поле, если select = 2 то скрываем и делаем не обязательным
            $('#sel1').prop('required', true);  // делаем обязательным поле
            $('#dop1').removeClass('hidden'); // Убираем класс, который скрывает поле
        } else {
            $('#sel1').prop('required', false); // делаем не обязательным
            $('#dop1').addClass('hidden'); // Добавляем класс, который скрывает поле.
        }
    }
```

```css
    .bobik{
        background: #9ED3E9;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    .hidden {
        visibility: hidden;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="sel1" class="bobik" onchange="change1()">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
</select>
<div id="dop1" required>Дополнительное поле</div>
```

Вот второй пример для наглядности(Добавил в случае выбора первого селекта - скрытие поля и убирание обязательности, чтобы можно было вернуть)

```js
    function change1() {
        let val = $('#sel1').val(); //Получаем значение поля селект.
        if (val !== ""){ //Если значение 1 2 или 3 то добавляем "required" и удаляем класс "hidden" , который скрывает поле, если поле ""(первый селект) То скрываем и делаем не обязательным
            $('#sel1').prop('required', true);  // делаем обязательным поле
            $('#dop1').removeClass('hidden'); // Убираем класс, который скрывает поле
        } else {
            $('#sel1').prop('required', false); // делаем не обязательным
            $('#dop1').addClass('hidden'); // Добавляем класс, который скрывает поле.
        }
    }
    function change2() {
        let val = $('#sel2').val();
        if (val !== ""){
            $('#sel2').prop('required', true);
            $('#dop2').removeClass('hidden');
        } else {
            $('#sel2').prop('required', false);
            $('#dop2').addClass('hidden');
        }
    }
```

```css
<style>
    .bobik{
        background: #9ED3E9;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    .hidden {
        visibility: hidden;
    }
</style>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="sel1" class="bobik" onchange="change1()">
    <option></option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
</select>
<div id="dop1" class="hidden">Дополнительное поле</div>
<select id="sel2" class="bobik" onchange="change2()">
    <option></option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
</select>
<div id="dop2" class="hidden">Дополнительное поле</div>
```

Вот пример с одним селектом, как указано в вопросе:

Comment: спасибо, то что надо !